# Best way to sort R list to get timeseries and use ggplot2

Tags: r, list, sorting, ggplot2

I´m working with the package `SPEI`. I run it and everything works. As result I got a list call `SPI` where de NA are not a problem.

```
    Jan           Feb           Mar           Apr           May
1980            NA            NA            NA            NA            
1981            NA            NA            NA            NA            
1982 -0.9762350127 -0.6462501217 -0.3858347460 -0.4001613574
```

And I plot this using `plot(SPI)`. I would like to use others packages like `ggplot2`, `plotly`.

So my question is, Which could be the better way to sort my data to work easily with it.

Comment: I think it's a matter of choice between each package - I use ggplot2 when plotting SPEI data. Once you have it in a dataframe, you can create additional attributes you might need for your figure (e.g. sign of the data).

Comment: The best way to sort your data to work easily with it would be hands down to apply the principles of what's known as "Tidy Data".  [This link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) and [this paper](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) have vital information on that.  Applying to the dataset above, I would organize with column headers being: `Date` and `Value`.  You can easily plot the data with `ggplot2` and convert to summary tables for illustration using `dplyr` and `tidyverse` tools and commands.